# Many times test with different config

Tags: java, junit

I am wondering, if I can run this same test many times but with different configuration.

For example: test called 'A' , run with config from file 'config1.json' and after it's done , run this same test 'A' with config from file 'config2.json'.

I can write test 'B' with config from 'config2.json' but I don't want duplicate my code.

Is it possible in JUnit ??

Comment: Yes, it is possble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JUnit 5

You can use [parametrized tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) if you are using JUnit 5:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"config.json", "config2.json"})
public void testMyCode(final String configResource) {
    // ...
}
```

*Note that parameterized tests are an experimental feature, as of 2018-09-19.*
They do work, but the API may change in future JUnit releases.

### JUnit 4

With JUnit 4 you would need to write a test scenario method and call it with different parameters from the test method:

```
@Test
public void testMyCode() {
    myTestScenario("config.json");
    myTestScenario("config2.json");
}

private void myTestScenario(final String configResource) {
    // ...
}
```